# File writing and reading

Tags: python

```
try:
   studfile = open("students.csv","r")
except IOError:
   studfile = open("students.csv","w")

#later in the code
studfile.write(students)
```

The purpose of this try/except block was to try and route out the IOError, but I ended up getting another error message, which was "*expected a character buffer object*". help on how to fix it?

Comment: to check if a file exhist better to use [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists). Also is `students` a string?

Comment: Post us both the error itself, and the lines of code causing the error. Also, what version of Python?

Comment: Your `try/except` block is _very_ weird. If the file already exists, it will open it in read-only mode, so the `studfile.write` will fail with an `IOError`. That can't be what you want. That's a separate problem from the one you're trying to fix, but you have to fix _both_ of them.

Comment: Meanwhile, as has already been explained, if you don't show us what `students` is and/or how you create it, we can't tell you how to fix it. People can throw a million guesses at you, but the odds that one will be right—or that you'll recognize the one that happens to be right—are pretty slim. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help.

Comment: @Marcin no students is a list mixed with strings and floats

Answer (score 0):

This is the `TypeError` you are getting. Your 'students' type should be string while writing to file. Using `str(students)` should solve your problem.

EDIT:
`str` can convert any object to `string` type. Considering the comments below:
Since you didn't mention the type of `student`. If it is list of string (assuming). Then you can't write like this: `studfile.write(students)`.

You should do similar to this:

```
for entry in students:
    studfile.write(entry)  # decide whether to add newline character or not
```

Comment: How do you know it will solve the problem. We do not know the type of `students` yet, so `str(students)` may or may not work

Comment: I think he hit the problem but missed the solution.

Comment: @jamylak @Lord Henry Wotton. I mentioned: `str(students)` to write into the file, since 'str()` can convert any object to `string` type. I think, rest he can pretend what to do next.

Comment: @jamylak `students` is very likely a list he forgot to `.join()`. You are right that running `str` would get rid of the syntactic error, but at the same time, it wouldn't necessarily fix the actual mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `students` is some form of data you wish to save as a `csv` file, it's probably best to use python's built in [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) file IO. For example:

```
import csv
with open("students.csv","wb") as studfile:   # using with is good practice
    ...
    csv_writer = csv.writer(studfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(students)            # assuming students is a list of data
```